# Vue - Dynamically add specific v-model name with v-for, not just an index

Tags: vue.js

I want to loop over the `colorMenus` array and bind my v-model to the already defined data elements `headerColor` and `checkboxColor`

I have this simplified code:

```
<v-card
  v-for="(colorMenu, index) in colorMenus"
  :key="index"
>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <p class="font-weight-bold text-subtitle-2 mt-4">{{ colorMenu.title }}</p>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="8">
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="myModels.color[index]"
        v-mask="mask" 
        hide-details 
        class=""
        solo
      ></text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-card>
```

And my data looks like this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      headerColor: '#1976D2FF',
      checkboxColor: '#1976D2FF',
      myModels: {
        color: ['headerColor', 'checkboxColor']
      },
      colorMenus: [
        {
          title: 'HEADER:',
        },
        {
          title: 'CHECKBOX:',
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

What's weird is I can get this, the model names, but they have # in front?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you've defined strings inside of that `color` array. You should refer to these items like this:

```
 myModels: {
     color: [this.headerColor, this.checkboxColor]
 },
```

Comment: no, you can't access `this` inside of `data`

Comment: False, you can't refer in context of other data objects, but you can use `this`, for example referring to props. Although you were right, this might not work

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. in a v-for for some reason I cannot access the name from an array, but I can if I access the data by key from ANOTHER object. No idea why, but it worked! Here is the fixed code:

```
<v-card
  v-for="(colorMenu, index) in colorMenus"
  :key="index"
>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <p class="font-weight-bold text-subtitle-2 mt-4">{{ colorMenu.title }}</p>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="8">
      <v-text-field 
        v-model="myModels[colorMenu.type]"
        v-mask="mask" 
        hide-details 
        class=""
        solo
      ></text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-card>
```

And then my data:

```
  export default {
    data() {
    return {
      headerColor: '#1976D2FF',
      checkboxColor: '#1976D2FF',
      myModels: {
        headerColor: '#1976D2FF',
        checkboxColor: '#1976D2FF',
      },
      colorMenus: [
        {
          title: 'HEADER:',
          type: 'headerColor'
        },
        {
          title: 'CHECKBOX:',
          type: 'checkboxColor'
        }
      ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using computed property? This works, you can try it out here

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-herschel-7q4u54?file=/src/App.vue

```
data() {
  return {
    headerColor: "#1976D2FF",
    checkboxColor: "#1976D2FF",
  };
},

computed: {
  myModels() {
    return [this.headerColor, this.checkboxColor];
  },
},
```